# How can I keep an SQL_Query in memory so it does not run each time?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pycharm

I regularly pull data from SQL Server by using `pd.read_sql_query()` method. Some databases are large so it takes a bit of time to execute.

Then I take that DataFrame and play around with it, but every time I run the code, python starts the process from the start: connects to the SQL server, finds the data, pulls the data etc and then continues running my code.

How can I keep the SQL Query in memory so it skips that step, so when I run my code it will retrieve the SQL Query from its memory rather than downloading from the network all over again?

EDIT: To clarify a bit better, I pull data from an SQL Database into a DataFrame and then just work on the DataFrame with pandas, such as format the rows, columns etc. To test my code I run the program and it runs the SQL query each time thus wasting time.

I am using PyCharm.

Comment: maybe you want to save the data locally?  or work in batches...  details would depend a lot on what you mean by "large" and "play around with it".  maybe edit the question to include a cutdown workflow

Comment: Store the results of the query.

Comment: @dfundako how do I do that?

Comment: If this was for a production system you could use caching/memoization, but since it sounds like you are just developing the easiest approach would be to run your query, save the output to disk, then on future runs just load the saved output instead of querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.  The following come to mind as reasonable approaches:

First, re-running the query might make sense because the underlying data changes.  So, your current approach is a viable option.

Second, you can stash the data locally into a file.  That is probably the most sensible solution, because this seems to be an application-side issue.  The application can have an option to use the saved results or re-run the query.

Third, you could run the query and save the results manually in a table.  This is really a variation of the second option, but the storage is in the database.

Fourth, you could define a materialized view.  This is like stashing a table, but the database will keep the materialized view up-to-date if underlying data changes (the "up-to-dateness" may be after a delay).